# Iget data from 1 table and check the data does not exist in second table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables created forum groups and group_members I want to get groups only those which are not in group members along with user id currently it is getting group which group id and user id is not present in the group members table if data is not in the table only if 1 group member exist it pulls up the record . In simple words I want to show show groups which user have not joined here is my table schema for both 3 tables

```
Groups
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | group 1  |
| 2  | group 2  |
| 3  | group 3  |
| 4  | group 4  |
+----+----------+

forums
+------------------+-------------+
| id | title       | group_id    |
+------------------+-------------+
| 1  | test 1      |           2 |
| 2  | test 2      |           3 |
| 3  | test 3      |           2 |
| 4  | test 4      |           3 |
| 5  | test 5      |           2 |
| 6  | test 6      |           4 |
+------------------+-------------+

Group_members
+-----------------+-------------+
| id | user_id  |  group_id    |
+-----------------+-------------+
| 1  | 107       |     2        |
| 2  | 106       |     3        |
+-----------------+-------------+
```

Here is my sql I have written

```
<?php
$sql_grp_chk = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM group_members WHERE groups.id == group_members.group_id)");
foreach($sql_grp_chk->result() as $data_ct):
    $sql_gr_coun = $this->db->query("SELECT groups.*, (SELECT count(group_id) FROM forums WHERE groups.id = forums.group_id) as forumcount FROM groups WHERE groups.id != '".$data_ct->id."' ORDER BY forumcount DESC LIMIT 5");
    foreach($sql_gr_coun->result() as $data_count):
        $sql_follow = $this->db->get_where('group_members', array('group_id' => $data_count->id));
        var_dump($data_count);
?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Use NOT IN instead of NOT EXISTS

Comment: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN (SELECT * FROM group_members WHERE groups.id = group_members.group_id AND use' at line 1

Comment: There is no "user id" in your tables.

Comment: @AlexBlex sorry check now

Comment: There should not be == in select query.

Comment: @SwetaParmar I am stilll getting the same error

Comment: Make sure you gave table names and column names correctly.\

Comment: as you can see the tables and query I am unable to see any erro rplease check if you found any ?

Comment: I tried your NOT EXISTS query it works properly may be some where else you are getting error,

Comment: I tried this Query: SELECT * FROM  i_mobile_app_registration_mst WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  i_mobile_app_registration_temp WHERE  i_mobile_app_registration_mst.mapr_register_id =  i_mobile_app_registration_temp.temp_id)

Comment: I am also getting correclty but if no user id exist in group memebers then I get 0 records

Comment: "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM group_members WHERE groups.id = group_members.group_id AND user_id = '$user_id')" With this query I am getting group which I have joined

Comment: foreach($sql_grp_chk->result() as $data_ct):
                    echo $data_ct->user_id;

Comment: I got 0 rows this means this is perfectly fine right now problem is in second query right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why `forums` is there, but to select all groups that are not linked to a user you can do `left join`:

```
select g.* from groups g
left join group_members m on m.group_id = g.id and m.user_id = :userId
where m.id is null;
```

**EDIT:**

Select top 5 groups, by number of forums linked:

```
select g.*, count(nullif(f.id, 1)) as cnt from groups g
inner join forums f on f.group_id = g.id
group by g.id
order by cnt desc
limit 5;
```

Both queries together - top 5 groups, by number of forums linked, which user has not joined yet:

```
select g.*, count(nullif(f.id, 1)) as cnt from groups g
left join group_members m on m.group_id = g.id and m.user_id = :userId
left join forums f on f.group_id = g.id
where m.id is null
group by g.id
order by cnt desc
limit 5;
```

Comment: forums is thEre because Those are to be shown which users haven't joined and the groups which have more forums posted on that group as you will notice in forums there is a group id as well

Comment: won't pretend I understand the comment, but how it is related to "show groups which user have not joined" question?

Comment: well simple words there is a panel of fetured groups where users can join secondly on that feautred box only those groups are shown on which greater amount of forums have been posted so that is why I am first checking if user id exist in the group members and group id is not exist then it will check that how many forums has been posted in particular group and als

Comment: never mind, I added couple of examples of how to fetch data in a single query rather than making multiple queries in a loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot you really helped me out